# Rails link_to anchor within partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, anchor

In my Rails 3 app I have a `link_to` that takes the User from their profile page to the settings page. The settings page contains a form `:partial` for editing a profile. What I'd like to do is have the `link_to` in the Profile take the User to an anchor in the form partial. I've given it a go but am having trouble.

As my `link_to` I have:

```
<%= link_to('Visit the info section', settings_path, {:anchor => 'info'}) %>
```

Within settings_path is `<%= render :partial => 'profiles/edit_settings_form' %>`

Within that partial is:

```
<div class="infoBlock" anchor="#info">
</div>
```

I have a route for settings that I thought was causing the error:

```
match "/settings" => "settings#show", :as => 'settings'
```

I tried adding another match for the anchor to "profiles#edit_settings_form" but it didn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

```
<div class="infoBlock" anchor="#info">
```

is not proper way to do an anchor to a page. Correct syntax is something similar:

```
<a name="anchor"></a>
```

Now when you got to page with pagename#anchor, it redirects you to that block. For example:

```
<%= link_to "Block in home", :action => "home", :anchor => "anchor" %>
```